# grant access to XML file on step over folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting

i have 2 asp.net web applications: admin_panel, site 
and i have uploaded them to windows web hosting (Godaddy) to separate folders
i have created folders from IIS management for each of them.
`admin_panel` works with `opinion.xml` db file which located in the same directory 
but when i am trying to use this xml file from another folder it gives me an error: `Access to the path ***xml is denied` 
P.S in connection string i used full path of this folder: `D:\Hosting\****\opinion.xml`
What about to grant permissions to xml file, there are no any option to grant it, if i am trying throw FTP client, it returns to `xxx mode` automatically
Please help are there any solution to solve it?
My be i can give permissions from `site` **web.config** or **code**

Comment: Check that you are using the same Application Pool for the both applications

Comment: No, not the same, because i have created difference app pool

Comment: So, that's the reason of your problem. Different Pools with different owners cannot access the same file. Because one has permissions, another hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Open **IIS -> Application Pools**

Click Advanced Settings for your both pools and select **Process Model -> Identity "NetworkService"**

Provide Read/Write **permissions for Network and Network Service** for the physical folder with your xml.

Comment: Thank you for reply, problem in my hosting, i have no access to IIS